# Does Corda State entries will be removed from persistent schema once that particular state is consumed?

Tags: blockchain, corda

As I understand all states instances created of a particular state (say CarState) will be there in the mapped persistent schema table.

My question is, will it stays there once an instance is consumed in an exit transaction (means no output state, like Delete command)?

Or is it something we can configure?

Answer (score 1):

Consuming a state does not remove it from the database - it merely sets its status to consumed.
The availability of consumed states is vital to enable checking of the backchain. Taking your car example - if you sell me your car, the transaction consumes your car state and create a car state owned by me. If I now want to sell on the car, the buyer might want to check that I rightfully own the car I am selling, and therefore can check the transaction that transferred ownership to me, and then possible the transaction that created its inputs all the way to the issuance/creation of the original car state. That required that all of the history is available in the database.

Deleting things from the database is a process called that is called "archiving" in Corda terms, and is generally a hard problem. Obviously, node operators are interested in not having the vault database growing indefinitely, or store older states that are unlikely to be needed in some cheaper long term storage. Also, there might be states that cannot be reached anymore in any backchain from live states, but figuring that out generally on a platform level is tricky.

Depending on your specific use case, there might be a relatively straight forward solution, but that needs domain/application level knowledge. E.g. you might delete the whole chain of car sales once the car gets written off/deregistered.

Comment: I think I confused you, I just want to know whether a consumed state in an exit transaction will be still present in the persistent schema table. I know it will be in vault as blob. I am considering the schema table alone.

Comment: Yes the persistent state will remain in the persistent schema table even after a contract state associated with it is consumed.

Comment: Thank you Sneha. I found somewhere it is something we configure. like only when devmode = true. I hope it is not, but for enterprise production scenario also it is the same. (meaning, the table row will be there for already consumed states)